# How to create an algorithms for fitting a network of tubes into a cube?

Tags: algorithms

How to create an algorithms for fitting a network of tubes with a range of diameters into a cube, with maximum volume in the tubes? Assume:

- 30 cm minimum square side
- 1 cm minimum pipe diameter
- 1 mm pipe wall thickness.
- Cube edge length $L$
- number of different diameters $n$
- volume Pipes $= \pi r^2\times\text{length}$.

The tubes form a network in the sense of a continuous network of connected Tubes.

Tricky parts:

- Finding the ideal number of different radiuses of pipes to use.
- accounting for curves in the pipes. May be worth assuming straight pipes with U-turns at the ends? Obviously square pipes would be ideal. But we are restricted to circular pipes.

Best to break down the problem into components:

1. assuming (one) 1 cm diameter pipe, how to fit most volume pipe into 30cm cube.
2. assuming (multiple) diameter pipes: 1 cm and 5 cm diameter pipes, how to fit most volume pipe into 30 cm cube.
3. how to determine the optimal number of diameters
   i. given limited number or radii,
   ii. given unlimited number of radii.

Comment: In what sense do the tubes form a network?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The tubes form a network in the sense of a continuous network of connected Tubes.